# Redirecting to /dev/null and a file at the same time

Tags: linux, redirection, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to execute the following command:
find . -name "*.[ch]*" | xargs grep -in pattern > file

There are some errors that are printed on stderr because a few files are not found. How can I redirect stdout to a file and stderr to /dev/null/ in the same command?

This command didn't work:
find . -name "*.[ch]*" | xargs grep -in pattern 1> file 2> /dev/null/

The error message: ksh: /dev/null/: cannot create [Is a directory]

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Cheers,
VSN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typed `/dev/null/` where it should be `/dev/null` !

```
find . -name ".[ch]" | xargs grep -in pattern 1> file 2> /dev/null
```

should work...

Comment: I feel really silly. Yeah, that worked... 0_0
Thanks a lot, sincerely! :)

Comment: This kind of things happens even to the best ones among us. :) Happy I could help you.